# How to write a function in file and include it everywhere in R?

Tags: r, function

In R, I want to write a function which can be imported everywhere.
For example:

```
>myfunc<-function() {
    print("hello world")
}
>myfunc()
```

It's can work on console, however, when then function become more complex or more universal, how can I import it when I start R console next time? Is it just create my own package or there are some other convinient method? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you need but i have a file which contains all my functions and i include the code with:

```
source("C:\\Temp\\my_functions.txt")
```

Comment: You can throw this in the .Rprofile and have it sourced every time you start R.  Though packages are so easy to make these days.